# Сохранение картинок, к которым применены фильтры css

Tags: javascript, php, css3

Интересует вопрос. Можно ли сохранить картинку, к которой применены фильтры с помощью css? Если можно, то как это сделать?

Comment: 'заскриншотить' с помощью canvas

Comment: Можно пример кода?